# How to prove a case of generalised partition is equivalent to fibonacci numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, summation, proof-writing, fibonacci-numbers

Let $k=m+\sum^{m+1}_{j=1} a_j$ such that $a,m,k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a_1$ or $a_{m+1}\geq 0$ with all other $a\geq1$. Note that we assume natural numbers start from $0$ and we have the restriction that $\sum^{m+1}_{j=1} a_j\geq m-1$. Why are there $F_{k+2}$ solution sets for values of $m$ and $a_\zeta$, for all $1\leq\zeta\leq m$? Can this be proven?

For example, when $k=4$, we have $8$ solution sets,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\{m,A\}&=\{0,\{4\}\},\\
&=\{1,\{3,0\}\},\\
&=\{1,\{0,3\}\},\\
&=\{1,\{1,2\}\},\\
&=\{1,\{2,1\}\},\\
&=\{2,\{0,1,1\}\},\\
&=\{2,\{1,1,0\}\},\\
&=\{2,\{0,2,0\}\},\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $A=\bigcup^{m+1}_{j=1} a_j$. Note that $\{2,\{1,0,1\}\}$ is invalid since only the first or final $a$'s may be $0$. Also, $\{3,\{0,1,0\}\}$ is invalid since $\sum^{m+1}_{j=1} a_j\geq m-1$.

(See Phicar's answer).

**New Question:**

Why is the number of solutions whereby there are nonzero last elements for the second set equivalent to $F_{k+1}$? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, notice that $b_j=a_j-1$ for $1<j<m+1$ and equal for the extremes implies that
$$k=2m-1+\sum _{j=1}^{m+1}b_j$$
So, by **stars and bars**, for a fixed $m$, you have that the number of solutions of $k-2m+1=b_1+\cdots +b_{m+1}$ is $$\binom{k-2m+1+m+1-1}{m+1-1}=\binom{k-m+1}{m}.$$
So, the number of these sequences is
$$\sum _{m=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1-m}{m}.$$
Can you show that this corresponds to $F_{k+2}$? **Hint:** Show that these expression satisfies the recursion of Fibonacci.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get $\frac{1}{k!\left(-k\right)!}+\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\left(\frac{\left(k-m-1\right)!}{m!\left(k-2m-1\right)!}+\frac{\left(k-m\right)!}{m!\left(k-2m\right)!}\right)=\sum_{m=0}^{k+1}\frac{\left(k+1-m\right)!}{m!\left(k+1-2m\right)!}$ from Fibonacci recursion on your sum, which seems too complicated. Is induction on the recursive identity the correct method instead of proving that the above equation holds for all $k$?

Comment: @UNOwen Do not use factorials, use Pascal's recursion for binomial numbers. Yes, strong induction.

Comment: Assuming no mistake on my behalf, are there any combinatorial identities to simplify the LHS of the last line of my proof attempt before performing strong induction on the sum (which I have edited into the original post – ignore the equals signs)? The second line uses Pascal's recursion for binomial numbers. Thank you for all your help, by the way.

Comment: @UNOwen Well the think is that those are binomial numbers. So, if you write them as binomial numbers, you will see it inmediately. Cause instead of $k+1$ you will have $k$ and $k-1$ on the top of the binomial.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: what binomial numbers/coefficients are you referring to (i.e. is it the LHS of last line of proof or is it earlier)? It might be clearer if you included some maths.

Comment: @UNOwen I am just saying that leave the symbols alone, without factorials, just use that $\binom{k+1-m}{m}=\binom{k-m}{m}+\binom{k-m}{m-1}$. When you distribute the sum, you will see the same expression appearing for $k$ and if you do $k-m=k-1-(m-1)$ you will have a $k-1$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.